# sound design in 'Hard Candy'

Tags: adr, production, dialogue-recording

has anyone else seen/ heard hard candy?

i would recommend it as the sound design on that film is really great,,. the whole film seems very sterile almost as if they didnt record any sound on production and the main character Jeff must of had his dialogue recorded in an anechoic chamber and has a VO quality to it..

Makes me wonder how they got the sound so clean and sterile sounding (other than good eqing), would they have just recorded very good production audio or was it all adr?

be great if anyone had any insight into this.. i know the budget for the film was only a million (only hehe)..

cheers

Comment: I'll see if I can find out - I worked with David Slade on 30 Days of Night & he has a great ear for sound

Comment: ps there is one sound in Hard Candy in particular that is excruciating! With giving away any spoilers, you'll know the sound I mean!!

Comment: yes... i dont think many a man would want to remember that sound.. chicken gibblets in a thick hot sauce perhaps? hehe